# Retrying after 500 http server error, continuing from the last line used in the file

Tags: python, http, loops, error-handling, line

I have created a code that ads users from a list, see below;

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        username, password, textfile = line.split(':')
        s.login(username, password)
    file = open(textfile.rstrip('\n'), 'r')         
    for line in file:
        s.add_friend(line) 
        print "Added: " + line,
        print "To account: " + username
        print "Sleeping for:",
        randomtime = random.uniform(.5, 1)
        print randomtime,
        print "seconds"
        time.sleep(randomtime)
    randomtime2 = random.uniform(300, 600)
    print "Timeout till next account, waiting: "
    print randomtime2,
    print "seconds"
    time.sleep(randomtime2)
```

The problem is here, that I indecently get a 500http error code.
It would be cool if I could use a system that retries, but without starting ALL over again.
So it'd need to start with the last name it added.

The names are in lines in a file.
like so:

```
USN1
USN2
USN3
USN4
USN5
```

So lets create a scenario here: (In command prompt)

```
The user USN1 is added!
The user USN2 is added!
The user USN3 is added!
requests.exceptions.HTTPError 500http error code
```

What I want the script to do right now is the following:

Retry and start over with USN3 to end.

So like this:

```
The user USN1 is added!
The user USN2 is added!
The user USN3 is added!
requests.exceptions.HTTPError 500http error code
The user USN3 is added!
The user USN4 is added!
The user USN5 is added!
etc...
```

Is there a way to save the line it's currently on and retry from that point?

I was thinking that I could just delete every username from the list once it's added and start the file all over again when retrying.
But this seems kinda like a ghetto solution and is not really what I'm looking for.

I was wondering if someone knows a solution to this, because I certainly don't, and I have looked for more than a hour already.

Happy thanksgiving and thanks in advance to anyone that can help me ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        username, password, textfile = line.split(':')
        s.login(username, password)
    file = open(textfile.rstrip('\n'), 'r')         
    for line in file:
        ok = False
        while not ok:
            try:
                s.add_friend(line) 
                ok = True
            except:
                time.sleep(1)
        print "Added: " + line,
        print "To account: " + username
        print "Sleeping for:",
        randomtime = random.uniform(.5, 1)
        print randomtime,
        print "seconds"
        time.sleep(randomtime)
    randomtime2 = random.uniform(300, 600)
    print "Timeout till next account, waiting: "
    print randomtime2,
    print "seconds"
    time.sleep(randomtime2)
```

Comment: very interesting, am I correct when I say this checks for an error first, before sending the line (username) and when no error, it sends the username, when error, it sleeps for a second.

Comment: Yes! The `while` keeps looping until `s.add_friend(line)` has been executed without error.

Comment: Very cool! could you please explain to me, what does "ok = false" and "while not ok" ? Does this track down the error? is there a way to execute different things for different error codes? for example, try again with 500 error code, move to next account for a 400 error code? (400 error code most likely means the account got temp. locked for some reason, doesn't happen quite often though)

Comment: The `ok` boolean indicates wheather or not the current user has been created. Before trying, it is `False`. Once it works, it becomes `True`. To answer your second question, we could try and detect whether the error is 400 or 500 in the `except` part...